# Need assistance adding double for one parameter based on another parameter

Tags: java

I am looking for Java coding assistance with how to add the numbers in one of my parameters based on the information of another parameter.

Sample data:

```
Customer # 1                        Customer # 2
Year      # of days                 Year      # of days              
2002         24                     2002         42
2003         53                     2003         91     
2004         16                     2004         38
2005         86                     2005         67
```

How would I add the number of days based on the years? The years given can be for any years past so it is not set years. Basically if I have 20 customers and 5 of them have a year of 1997, how would I total their number of days?

Comment: Have you tried anything? If not give it a go and if you're stuck post your queries here, we'll take a look

Comment: Do you have a third column of relevant data on a customer? The year doesn't seem to be a unique column.

Comment: Nicholas, I am new in developing and completely stumped on where to even start.

Comment: Christian, I am just looking for a total of days based on the year. It will be unique customer numbers that has different years of information for their customer number and each year has a different number of days.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question, but maybe look into the `Dictionary` class (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Dictionary.html). It lets you store 2 values with the first one (I guess the year in your case) acting as a key.

Comment: This will be used for a report. Based on the sample data I provided, I am looking for something that will look like this.

Comment: Total days by year: 2002  - 66, 2003 - 144, 2004 - 54, 2005 - 153

Comment: Ok I think I understood your question. You can store the year as a `key` in a `HashMap`. As you iterate over this collection you will need to check if the `key` is already present in the map. If it is get the previous value and add the new one to it. If it's not present then just set the value to the `key`. This is a simple pseudo-algorithm that you can try to implement.

Comment: Thank you, Nicholas. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Sincere request to everyone else not to just give the answer away on this one.*

I'm not giving the answer straight away, as that may not help you. Instead I've given you a hint; a `pseudocode` try it out yourself - happy coding.

You can store the year as a key in a `HashMap`. Here the `key` is the 'year' and the `value` is the 'number of days'.

As you iterate over this collection you will need to check if the `key` is already present in the map. If it is get the previous value and add the new one to it. If it's not present then just set the value to the `key`. This is a simple pseudo-algorithm that you can try to implement.